# Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V not working in VB6

Tags: vb6, copy-paste, mdi, mdichild

i have a project in VB6. This project have a MDI form and many childs. My problem is Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V not working. But Copy / Paste with mouse run fine.

There is some configuration of the project to enable these functions?

I have another similar project and Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V run fine but i don't see any difference.

Thanks

Comment: What controls are you trying to copy/paste from/to?  Textboxes?  Rich text controls? Other?

Comment: I'm using Codejock OCX controls, but with standard controls like textbox does not work either

Comment: I use some of their controls as well.  Is it possible that you have a menu that has items that have been assigned the shortcut keys?  I've caught that in my own code, assigning ctrl-v to something, not thinking about how it would over-ride the paste command.  In my case, I just used shift-insert instead, but removing or changing the menu shortcut would probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks Bill, my program use a menu with Command Bars Designer of Codejock. I'll look for shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the creation of external menu, created with Command Bars Designer of Codejock. 
In this Command Bars Designer i can create "Accelerators": key combinations to which a function is assigned. Then Ctrl-C was a bad function.
Only delete this Accelerator and then run fine.

Thanks